# Adding one to the set of numbers in the array Java

Tags: java

```
public class Test                                       
{                                       
  public static int addOne(int[] numb)                                      
  {                                     
    for(int i=0;i<numb.length;i++){                                     
      System.out.println(numb[i]+1);                                        
      int result = numb[i];                                     
    }                                       
    return (numbers.length);                                        
  }                                     
}
```

Main:

```
public class Main                                       
{                                       
  public static void main(String[] args)                                        
  {                                     
    int[] numO = {2,2,4,4,6};                                       
    System.out.println(Test.addOne(numO)); /                                        
  }                                     
}
```

Output:

```
3,3,5,5,7,5
```

I was trying out arrays in java as I am starting to learn arrays, I set five numbers in the array and using a for loop, wanted to add the numbers in the array by 1, e.g. Array containing (1,2,3) would be (2,3,4) and outputting the total number 9, instead of 2,3,4 and a random number. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Really unclear what you want. You are already printing `array[i] + 1` (not storing it, just printing). You have no code to do any totals (i.e. no `a = a + b`). `numbers.length` ? There is no `numbers` so this doesn't even compile.

Comment: Looks to me like you're throwing code at the compiler in the hope something sticks. Why are you printing each number (+1)? What's the point of `result`? Why are you returning the array length? Don't complain that it doesn't work if you can't explain why it should.

Answer (score 0):

You are never actually changing the value contained within the numb array, what you are doing is taking the existing value and adding outputting it with 1 added to it

```
System.out.println(numb[i] + 1);
```

To change the value you must increment the value outside

```
numb[i]++;
System.out.println(numb[i]);
```

That should solve your problem of not retaining the changed value in the array. However there is another error that I can see that would prevent you from outputting the correct result value. By doing `result + numb[i];` you are preforming an operation but not setting the result variable equal to anything. To set it add to the value it already contains you would do `result = result + numb[i]` or more properly `result += numb[i]`

Hope this helps!